# How to geocode in google maps v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been looking through version 3 of the google maps api, and I have put together a small script to geocode an address. The problem is that I want to see If i can extract the lat lng without having to 'split()' the result.

```
function getLatLng() {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var query = "12 henry street, dublin 1, dublin, ireland";
  var address = query;   
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
      alert('Geocode succesful ' + latLng);
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });  
}
```

I want to get the lat and the lng from the `var latLng`.
Can this be done without calling latLng.split(',');?

Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var lat= results[0].geometry.location.lat();                     
var lng= results[0].geometry.location.lng();                     
alert(lat);  
alert(lng);
```

Comment: hi there. What's the wa and xa?

Comment: wa is the latitude and xa the longitude. You can write alert(results[0].toSource()); or alert(results.toSource()); to see all of the results object.

Comment: I see. One last question - where did you find this information? I couldn't find it anywhere on the google maps v3 site. Thanks so much for your time. kind regards

Comment: I am interested in gmaps geocoding, using v3. I had a different problem so I looked into the results object (using alert(results.toSource()); ).

Comment: Those are undocumented properties and should not be used, those names can change with every release of the API.

Answer (score 9):

Never use internal variables exposed by the API. They can and do change from release to release. Always use documented methods.

`results[0].geometry.location` is a `LatLng` object, so use the relevant methods:

```
var lat=results[0].geometry.location.lat();
var lng=results[0].geometry.location.lng();
```